# Creating an array list of multiple data types in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Some of the file I'm working with: http://pastebin.com/WriQcuPs

Currently I had to make the population, latitude, and longitude strings or else I wouldn't get the desired output. I want for them to be int, double, and double in that order.

```
public class City {
    String countrycode;
    String city;
    String region;
    String population;
    String latitude;
    String longitude;

    public City (String countrycode, String city, String region, String population, String latitude, String longitude) {
        this.countrycode = countrycode;
        this.city = city; 
        this.region = region;
        this.population = population;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.city + "," + this.population 
                + "," + this.latitude + ","
                + this.longitude; 
    }
}
```

---

I suspect it has something to do with how I created the array list. Is there a way to make it so that some of the elements of the list are of a different type? I tried changing it to `ArrayList<City>` and changing the data types in the `City` class but it still gave me a ton of errors.

```
public class Reader {

    In input = new In("file:world_cities.txt");
    private static City cityInfo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // open file
        In input = new In("world_cities.txt");
        input = new In("world_cities.txt");
        try {
        // write output to file
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("cities_out.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        int line = 0;

        // iterate through all lines in the file
        while (line < 47913) {

            // read line
            String cityLine = input.readLine();

            // create array list
            ArrayList<String> cityList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cityLine.split(",")));

            // add line to array list
            cityList.add(cityLine);

            // increase counter
            line += 1;      

            // create instance
            cityInfo = new City(cityList.get(0), cityList.get(1), cityList.get(2), cityList.get(3), cityList.get(4), cityList.get(5));
            System.out.println(cityInfo);

            // print output to file 
            pw.println(cityInfo); 
        }

        // close file
        pw.close();
        }

        // what is printed when there is an error when saving to file
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
        }

        // close the file
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the list as follows, you can put instances of any reference type into it:

```
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

But the downside is that when you get an element from the list, the static type of the element will be `Object`, and you will need to type cast it to the type that you need.

Also note, that you can't put an `int` or a `double` into a `List`.  Primitive types are not reference types, and the `List` API requires the elements to be instances of reference types.  You need to use the corresponding wrapper types; i.e. `Integer` and `Double`.

---

Looking at more of your code, I spotted this:

```
ArrayList<String> cityList = 
    new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cityLine.split(",")));
```

If you change the list to `List<Object>` where the objects are either `Integer` or `Double`, you won't be able to build your list like that.

In fact, the more I look this, the more I think that you don't need a list at all.  You should be doing something like this:

```
    // read line
    String cityLine = input.readLine();

    String[] parts = cityLine.split(",");
    // increase counter
    line += 1;      

    // create instance
    cityInfo = new City(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], 
                        Integer.parseInt(parts[3]),
                        Double.parseDouble(parts[4]),
                        Double.parseDouble(parts[5]));
```

Notice: there is no `List` there at all!!

Comment: Awesome! Works great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the string values before they are passed into a new `City` object. Then you could change the constructor and variables within a `City` to be an int, double, and double.

```
int pop = Integer.parseInt(cityList.get(3));
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(cityList.get(4));
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(cityList.get(5));
cityInfo = new City(cityList.get(0), cityList.get(1), cityList.get(2), pop, latitude, longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the `City` class you have defined the members are of different primitive data types. When you read the file to create a City, you need to pass the constructor parameters with the defined data types as in your constructor.

Modify your `City` class as below :

```
public class City {
    String countrycode;
    String city;
    String region;
    int population;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
...
```

Try the following :

```
cityInfo = new City(cityList.get(0), cityList.get(1), cityList.get(2), Integer.parseInt(cityList.get(3)), Double.parseDouble(cityList.get(4)), Double.parseDouble(cityList.get(5)));
```

This will convert the Strings to int and double as desired by the `City` class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe no, but you can do this

```
public class City {
String countrycode;
String city;
String region;
String population;
double latitude;
double longitude;

public City (String countrycode, String city, String region, String population, double latitude, double longitude) {
    this.countrycode = countrycode;
    this.city = city; 
    this.region = region;
    this.population = population;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.city + "," + this.population 
            + "," + this.latitude + ","
            + this.longitude; 
}
}

public class Reader {

In input = new In("file:world_cities.txt");
private static City cityInfo;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // open file
    In input = new In("world_cities.txt");
    input = new In("world_cities.txt");
    try {
    // write output to file
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("cities_out.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    int line = 0;

    // iterate through all lines in the file
    while (line < 47913) {

        // read line
        String cityLine = input.readLine();

        // create array list
        ArrayList<String> cityList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cityLine.split(",")));

        // add line to array list
        cityList.add(cityLine);

        // increase counter
        line += 1;      

        // create instance
        cityInfo = new City(cityList.get(0), cityList.get(1), cityList.get(2), cityList.get(3), Doule.parseDouble(cityList.get(4)), Doule.parseDouble(cityList.get(5)));
        System.out.println(cityInfo);

        // print output to file 
        pw.println(cityInfo); 
    }

    // close file
    pw.close();
    }

    // what is printed when there is an error when saving to file
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR!");
    }

    // close the file
    input.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

**READER CLASS**

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Reader {

    In input = new In("file:world_cities.txt");
    private static City cityInfo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // open file
//        In input = new In("world_cities.txt");
//        input = new In("world_cities.txt");
        try {
        // write output to file
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("cities_out.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        int line = 0;

        // iterate through all lines in the file
        while (line < 47913) {

            // read line
            String cityLine = input.readLine();

            // create array list
            ArrayList<String> cityList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cityLine.split(",")));

            // add line to array list
            cityList.add(cityLine);

            // increase counter
            line += 1;      

            // create instance
            cityInfo = new City(cityList.get(0), cityList.get(1), cityList.get(2), Integer.parseInt(cityList.get(3)), Double.parseDouble(cityList.get(4)), Double.parseDouble(cityList.get(5)));
            System.out.println(cityInfo);

            // print output to file 
            pw.println(cityInfo); 
        }

        // close file
        pw.close();
        }

        // what is printed when there is an error when saving to file
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
        }

        // close the file
        input.close();
    }
}
```

**CITY CLASS**

```
public class City {
    String countrycode;
    String city;
    String region;
    int population;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    public City (String countrycode, String city, String region, int population, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.countrycode = countrycode;
        this.city = city; 
        this.region = region;
        this.population = population;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.city + "," + this.population 
                + "," + this.latitude + ","
                + this.longitude; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make it so that some of the elements of the list are
>   of a different type?

It is possible to have a `List` with elements of different type, but not if you're populating it with `String.split()` -- because that returns a `String[]`.

You can convert the strings you get back fro `String.split()` into the desired types with the `valueOf` methods on the Java primitive type wrappers, for example...

```
Integer population = Integer.valueOf("1234567");  // Returns 1234567 as an Integer, which can autobox to an int if you prefer
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Stephen suggested, you can use `List<Object>`, besides that, you can just pass String to City but let City itself to handle the datatype.

```
public class City {
    String countrycode;
    String city;
    String region;
    int population;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    public City (String countrycode, String city, String region, String population, String latitude, String longitude) {
        this.countrycode = countrycode;
        this.city = city; 
        this.region = region;
        try{
            this.population = Integer.parseInt(population);
            this.latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
            this.longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStacktrace();
        }

    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.city + "," + this.population 
                + "," + this.latitude + ","
                + this.longitude; 
    }
}
```

Btw, you have initiated `In` twice.

```
In input = new In("world_cities.txt");
input = new In("world_cities.txt");
```

Modify it to

```
In input = new In("world_cities.txt");
```

Comment: Whoops! Good catch!