# How to store different types of objects in ArrayList

Tags: java

I need to store different objects in the ArrayList. Objects are similar in nature but different and have different methods.

```
Circle c = new Circle();  
Cube s = new Cube();
Piramid p = new Piramid();
ArrayList<?> list = new ArrayList<?>();
```

So what to use in  that I can use all the methods in the objects.

Comment: Write an interface and specify in that interface the methods you want to use. Have your shape classes all implement the interface. Also, pyramid is spelled with a "y"

Comment: The word you are looking for is 'Polymorphism' https://www.javaworld.com/article/3033445/learn-java/java-101-polymorphism-in-java.html

Comment: use interface type to insert into the arraylist and let all classes Circle, cube etc implement it...refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566983/java-arraylist-contains-different-objects

Comment: or simply use `ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();`. This does allow every type tp be stored

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an array list of multiple data types in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570285/creating-an-array-list-of-multiple-data-types-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

You *can* just create an `ArrayList<Object>`. That's a list that can store anything. It's not very useful to work with, because taking things out basically forces you to check their type in order to call any methods. For that reason you should almost always avoid doing this.

Objects in collections usually have something in common - if they don't, you should rethink *why* you're throwing them into the same collection. In your case, they're all shapes. So instead, consider adding a shared interface such as `Shape` which combines the common functionality.

I'm simplifying slightly because you have the concept of both 2D and 3D shapes, but here's the gist:

```
interface Shape
{
    double area();
    double perimeter();
}

class Circle implements Shape
{
    // ...

    public double area()
    {
        return radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }

    public double perimeter()
    {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }
}

class Square implements Shape
{
     //...
}
```

And then creating a list of `Shape`s:

```
List<Shape> shapes = Arrays.asList(new Circle(3), new Square(4), ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

you can call the all methods including Object class method.

Comment: you will be able to access only the methods of Object class and not the methods of the instances added in the arrayList

Answer (score 0):

i think you can create a list of objects, and when use someone u cast to the specific type

```
List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();

if (obj.get(i) instanceof Class) {
    Class objCast = (Class)obj 
}
```

[Objects DOC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do.

1. Define a Shape interface..
2. Implement the interface for Circle and Cube
3. Create shape objects for Circle and Cube and add these to arraylist..

Code below:

```
public interface Shape {

    public void draw();

}



public class Circle implements Shape {

@Override
public void draw() {
    System.out.println("Drawing Circle");

}

}



public class Cube implements Shape {

@Override
public void draw() {
    System.out.println("Drawing Cube");
}

}



public class Simulator{

public static void main(String[] s){

    Shape s1 = new Circle();
    Shape s2 = new Cube();

    ArrayList<Shape> shapeList = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    shapeList.add(s1);
    shapeList.add(s2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new ArrayList<>());
list.add(Integer.valueOf("24"));
list.add(Long.valueOf("25"));
list.add("STRING");
list.add(new Object());

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
//Console print: " [[], 24, 25, STRING, java.lang.Object@4554617c] "
```

You may store any object type.