# can i make an arraylist with 2 object from different class?

Tags: java

how can i make an arraylist in the main with 3 itineraries: one without stop (route) and name d1
,one with stop (indirectstop) and name d2, one without stop (route) and name d3.
So ,i ask if there is any way to make an arraylist with two objects from one class and one from other class

Code:

```
public class Route {
private int id;   
private int aeroplane; 
private String departure; 
private String arrival; 
private ArrayList<Ticket> Tickets  ;  

public Route(){ 
    id = 0 ;
    aeroplane = 0  ;
    departure = " "; 
    arrival = " ";  
    Tickets = new ArrayList<>();
    
}

public Route(int ID, int aerop, String depar,String arriv,ArrayList<Ticket> tick ){
    id=ID;
    aeroplane=aerop;
    departure=depar;
    arrival=arriv;
    Tickets=tick;}

 public void addTicket(Ticket tick)
{
 Tickets.add(tick);
}

@Override
public void finalize(){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("The id of the train is:");
    id=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The aeroplane code is:");
    aeroplane=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The departure is:");
    departure=input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("The arrival is:");
    arrival=input.nextLine();

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\nID: " + this.getId() + "\nAeroplane: " +this.getAeroplane() 
            + "\nDeparture: " + this.getDeparture() + "\nArrival" +this.getArrival() + "Tickets:" +this.getTickets();
}
```

And `IndirectRoute`, a subclass of `Route`.

```java
public class IndirectRoute extends Route { 
    private String middlestop; 
    
    public IndirectRoute() 
    { 
      super();
      middlestop = "";
    }
    public IndirectRoute(String middle, int ID, int aerop, String depar,String arriv, ArrayList<Ticket> tick)
    {
      super(ID,aerop,depar,arriv,tick);
      middlestop = middle;
    }

    public String getMiddlestop() {
        return middlestop;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return super.toString() + "middlestop=" + middlestop + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Not very clear what you want, anyway, to a `List<Object>` you can add any object.

Comment: You could also use an interface that each class implements

Comment: Why would you want a list of three unrelated types of objects?

Comment: If you store objects of different types you should test with instanceof every element due to understand which class it belongs to.

Comment: By the way, `finalize` is [deprecated for removal](https://openjdk.org/jeps/421).

Comment: I fixed some of your code samples’ formatting this time. The indenting still needs fixing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store different types of objects in ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703025/how-to-store-different-types-of-objects-in-arraylist)

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  a list may contain objects of a certain type as well as objects of a subclass of that type. [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) handles this.

Here is a compact example, all in one `.java` file.

```java
package work.basil.routing;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        List < Route > routes =
                List.of(
                        new Route() ,
                        new IndirectRoute() ,
                        new Route()
                );
    }
}

class Route
{
    public final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
}

class IndirectRoute extends Route
{
}
```

When we loop that list, Java can differentiate between elements of the superclass and elements of the subclass.

### Current Java

Currently we would use `instanceOf` to differentiate between elements of the superclass and elements of the subclass

Notice one crucial issue with the following code. We, as the programmer, are responsible for getting the order right. We must consciously test for subclasses before we test for superclasses. The IDE/compiler provide no feedback if we get this order wrong.

```java
for ( Route route : routes )
{
    String output = "OOPS! Unexpected type of `route`.";
    if ( route instanceof IndirectRoute )
    {
        output = "Instance of `IndirectRoute`, a subclass of `Route`. " + "Has ID: " + route.id;
    }
    else if ( route instanceof Route )
    {
        output = "Instance of `Route`. " + "Has ID: " + route.id;
    }
    System.out.println( "output = " + output );
}
```

When run.

```
output = Instance of `Route`. Has ID: 5a765835-40e4-4cc8-90e7-0687dd7f5362
output = Instance of `IndirectRoute`, a subclass of `Route`. Has ID: b57c9db3-8066-46d6-8f98-0d2d3fa4f835
output = Instance of `Route`. Has ID: a297586b-824e-4520-b760-1aebfd4e3446
```

### Future Java

In the future, we will likely be able to use [`switch` expressions](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361) combined with [pattern matching for `switch`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/427) to differentiate between elements of the superclass and elements of the subclass. This new approach will be more concise and will provide more clarity of the programmer’s intention.

Notice that unlike the `instanceof` code seen above, we *do* get assistance from the IDE/compiler regarding the ordering out our cases. In the code below, if we had `Route` listed before `IndirectRoute`, our tooling would indicate the problem and suggest a reordering with the subclass before the superclass.

Caveat: The pattern matching feature is not yet released. Currently previewed in Java 19 (and 18, and 17).

```java
for ( Route route : routes )
{
    String output =
            switch ( route )
                    {
                        case IndirectRoute x -> "Instance of `IndirectRoute`, a subclass of `Route`. " + "Has ID: " + route.id;
                        case Route y -> "Instance of `Route`. " + "Has ID: " + route.id;
                    };
    System.out.println( output );
}
```

When run.

```
Instance of `Route`. Has ID: 07152a33-5b98-4977-a62c-014e9fc3603d
Instance of `IndirectRoute`, a subclass of `Route`. Has ID: 448970bf-2c98-4310-8fff-2dbdac2d68c6
Instance of `Route`. Has ID: e9e7e0cb-0b28-420c-8dba-c2cb72007f2b
```